# Método de pagamento com dados diferentes para cada país

Tags: magento

O site possui o método de pagamento por transferência bancária.

O problema é que se o cliente reside no Brasil, então os dados bancários são de uma conta no Brasil, se o cliente é da Europa, os dados bancários são de um banco da Europa.

Estou a utilizar o módulo padrão do Magento.

Como faço para mostrar a informação correta para cada país?

É possível configurar o módulo padrão ou será necessário desenvolvimento?